# Elastic query for large text document match

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have an elastic index of news articles, with the news body text in a newsBody field, can you do a search to see if another newsBody 'matches' one in the index? The other newsBody text may have slight variations however.

So not exact matching, but being able to test for similarity between large bodies of text. This is important as often news articles will be nearly identical but differ in ~30 out of 400 words.

So I'd like to be able to pass in a newsBody, and query it against the whole index, looking for similarity to any 'matches'.

I think the similarity module may help, but haven't got anywhere yet: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Are you using JSON formatted queries with `curl`..? A client API in some programming language?

Comment: At the moment using kibana to do searches, but also use NEST in c#

Comment: I understand I could just do a match query, and say if score > N then it could be a 'duplicate' newsBody - is this the right way to go you think?

Comment: Depends on how fancily you need to define "similar". That method could be good enough for your use case, but if you need to define a custom meaning to how Elasticsearch is grading a "match", that might not be enough.